# Spring Webflow action-state else

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a problem with a webflow action-state. The structure I want is: 
*if...else if....else if .....else*

In my action state (see below),

- I call getTestTypeName();
- This method returns a string. There could be ten valid values
  although currently there are only two.
- However, I may also get an invald String which is not an error but
  needs to be sent to a specified view-state.
- How do I do this. Currently, I get an error

```html
<action-state id="selectPostITSAction">
    <evaluate expression="testEntranceViewService.getTestTypeName(flowScope.vwUser)" />
 
        <transition on="ProgramChoiceTemplate" to="paymentGateway" />
  
 <transition on="CPCFeedbackTemplate" to="report" >
  <evaluate  expression="testEntranceViewService.reactivateTestOnHold(vwUser, flowRequestContext)"
    result="flowScope.vwUser" />
 </transition>
  
 <transition on="error" to="entry" />
  
</action-state>
```

"Prototype Test Template1467832258812" is an invalid option but I cannot handle with webflow. I get this error is

> ExceptionNo transition was matched on the event(s) signaled by the [1] action(s) that executed in this action state 'selectPostITSAction' of flow 'flow-entry'; transitions must be defined to handle action result outcomes -- possible flow configuration error? Note: the eventIds signaled were: 'array['Prototype Test Template1467832258812']', while the supported set of transitional criteria for this action state is 'array[ProgramChoiceTemplate, CPCFeedbackTemplate, error]'org.springframework.webflow.engine.NoMatchingTransitionException

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it
The answer is to have a transition with no "on="

See below

```html
<action-state id="selectPostITSAction">
    <evaluate expression="testEntranceViewService.getTestTypeName(flowScope.vwUser)" />
 
        <transition on="ProgramChoiceTemplate" to="paymentGateway" />
  
 <transition on="CPCFeedbackTemplate" to="report" >
  <evaluate  expression="testEntranceViewService.reactivateTestOnHold(vwUser, flowRequestContext)"
    result="flowScope.vwUser" />
 </transition>
  
  <transition  to="expectedError" >
  
 <transition on="error" to="entry" />
  
</action-state>
```